# Why does this simple PHP code not work, yet the HTML does?

Tags: php, html, echo

The first section of code (PHP) will only work if I comment out the 3  lines.  The second section of code (HTML) works fine.  I've tried many different iterations of the syntax of the 3  lines, but cannot get it to work.

```
<?php
echo '<select id="question" name="question">';
echo '<option value="Don't care" >Don't care</option>';
echo '<option value="Yes" selected="selected" >Yes</option>';
echo '<option value="No" >No</option>';
echo '</select>';
?>

<select id="question" name="question">
<option value="Don't care" >Don't care</option>
<option value="Yes" selected="selected" >Yes</option>
<option value="No" >No</option>
</select>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Even the color highlighting on StackOverflow shows the issue..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a close look in here:

```
echo '<option value="Don't care" >Don't care</option>';
```

Make a little change in your code, hope it will work.

```
echo'<option value="Don\'t care" >Don\'t care</option>';
```

Answer (score 10):

You have a syntax error:

```
'<option value="Don't care"
```

The `'` in `Don't` prematurely terminates your string. You need to escape it:

```
echo '<option value="Don\'t care" >Don\'t care</option>';
```

Your editors syntax highlighting should make this very obvious, as Stack Overflow demonstrates. You can clearly see in your question that "t care" is strangely higlighted, a dead giveaway that your string isn't terminating when you think it is.

Comment: Upvoting, even though you really don't deserve this many upvotes.

Comment: Wow. Thank you very much.  And you are right, if I look very closely, my editor does show a slight difference in color.  Thanks again!!!

Comment: @MikeChristensen Best 20 second answer I ever posted.